Battery not detected on Ubuntu 22.04
Just got a new Charging port on my Dell inspirion replaced and now my battery isn’t being detected, unsure of whether this classifies as a Linux based issue however when I use upower -e the battery doesn’t show up either. Is there command that could reset the detection or is this a hardware issue.
